# Why is Jarque-Bera Test right value only returning 0?

Tags: python, pandas, normal-distribution

My code to test the jarque_bera is the following:

```
for x in data.columns.values:
    print(x, "-", stats.jarque_bera(data[x]))
```

and the result is

[image]

Does this mean that all columns of my dataframe are not normalized?

Comment: Well it's not *truly* 0, but the p-value is exceptionally small that it just displays 0. Either way you can easily reject the null hypothesis that your variables have the same skewness and kurtosis of the normal distribution. (Note that's not the same as "normalized" which generally has other meanings relating to some scaling of the values.)

Comment: Ok thanks! That was what I was thinking aswell

Comment: This is a statistics question more so than a programming one, no? Also, using screenshots to share information is discouraged, and should only be done when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jarque_bera` test is testing the null hypothesis that your values are distributed with the same skewness and kurtosis of the normal distribution.

What's happening is that for each test, your test statistic is sufficiently large that the p-values are exceedingly small so python just displays 0. Scipy uses the `cdf` to calculate the p-value which only gets down to `e-16`. Using the `sf` can give you decimals until it underflows.

```
from scipy import stats

stats.chi2.cdf(1154.1959249402914, 2)  
#1.0

# scipy reported p-value
1 - stats.chi2.cdf(1154.1959249402914, 2)
#0.0

# This function gives us decimals
stats.chi2.sf(1154.1959249402914, 2)
#2.3417438136962163e-251
```